# jQuery/JS: Activate two divs while deactivating all other when clicking on single div

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to make it so that **when I click on a div image the respective content box pops up** (i.e. a div turns from `display:none;` to `display:inline;`).

http://jsfiddle.net/sergep/gXRRw/

*['pop up' box = div with `content`]*

I'm using the simple JS to active the relevant div:

```
$('.diagram div').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.diagram div').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Currently the html looks like so:

```
<div class="diagram">
  <div class="gameboy"></div>
  <div class="switch"></div>
  <div class="face"></div>
</div>
<div class="diagram-content">
  <div class="gameboy-content">This is a content box for the gameboy</div>
  <div class="switch-content">This is a content box for the switch</div>
  <div class="face-content">This is a content box for the face</div>
</div>
```

The question is, should I encapsulate the content pop-ups inside the `.diagram` class? or have it in a separate `.diagram-content` class?

How do I modify the code to also add/append an `.active` class to the active box that should popup? Or is the best approach is to modify the css `display` of the relevant content box inside the `.click(function)`?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a class, you could use the HTML5 `data` attribute. You can use CSS selectors for these attributes if you want to implement the image changes with CSS as you have.

```
<div class="diagram">
  <div data-type="gameboy"></div>
  <div data-type="switch"></div>
  <div data-type="face"></div>
</div>
<div class="diagram-content">
  <div data-type="gameboy-content">This is a content box for the gameboy</div>
  <div data-type="switch-content">This is a content box for the switch</div>
  <div data-type="face-content">This is a content box for the face</div>
</div>
```

This helps isolate your styling from your content. You can access the `data` property using `$.data()`

```
$('.diagram div').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var type = $this.data('type');
  $this.siblings('.diagram div').removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');
  $('div.diagram-content [data-type=' + type + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

Note that you could achieve the same using plain CSS classes but it's always better to isolate your data from your view. In this case, isolating the styling of diagram content vs. the meaning of the content.

Comment: I see where you're getting at, but I've decided to take the classes approach for now! I'm still unsure what I'm doing wrong with the syntax (pluggin in an `alert` stops the code completely :S, so hard to test) - Is there a chance you could resolve this? http://jsfiddle.net/sergep/5uy7h/